# What is the number of solutions of $2a+2b+2c+d=n$

Tags: combinations

I have a equation and I need to find the number of possible integer solutions for it. The equation is of the form 
$$2a+2b+2c+d=n, (a,b,c,d > 0)$$

Comment: Have you tried searching. This question or one closely similar has come up several times in the last week.

Comment: Yes, I tried but I couldn't get a solution except for the general case with no restrictions

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602547/how-many-positive-integer-solutions-does-the-equation-x-y-z-w-15-have?rq=1, or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657515/how-many-solution-of-a-equations?rq=1.

Comment: It boils down to $\sum_k\binom{2k+2}{2}$ which should give a cubic. It's pretty straightforward but perhaps there are more clever solutions.

Comment: @VivekMaskara The restriction to positive integers is trivially dealt with. Anyway the idea is to help you solve things yourself, not provide solution service! :)

Comment: yep positive integers is no longer a problem. @Burde's link helped

Comment: Is there any restriction on $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Use the generating function of the LHS:

$$f(x) = (x^2+x^4+x^6+...)^3(x+x^2+x^3+...)$$

and the answer for the equation is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating function.

To get the cofficient, we split to disjoint events, by the size of $d$, obviously that if $n$ is even/odd then $d$ is even/odd, and then divide $n-d$ by $2$ and split it to $3$ different cells with repetitions $$CC_3^{\frac{n-d}{2}}$$

Then sum over all those events.

Comment: Finding that coefficient is exactly the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

---

Let $a+b+c=k$, then we have $2k+d=n$. Now for any given value of $d$  there is corresponds $3$ values of $k$. So for $m$ values of $d$ we have $3m$ values of $k$

So that we are going to have ... solutions.